# In selenium webdrive how to login in gmail and get activation code by using mail subject

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, gmail, gmail-api

```
public String getAuthorizationCode(String account) throws Exception {
    Message email = getMessagesBySubject("Email Subject "+ account, true, 5)[0];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(email.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    String prefix = "userId:";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      if(line.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return line.substring(line.indexOf(":") + 1);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

//  public Message[] getMessagesBySubject(String subject, boolean unreadOnly, int maxToSearch) throws Exception{
    Map indices = getStartAndEndIndices(maxToSearch);

```
Message messages[] = folder.search(
    new SubjectTerm(subject),
    folder.getMessages(indices.get("startIndex"), indices.get("endIndex")));

if(unreadOnly){
  List<Message> unreadMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
  for (Message message : messages) {
    if(isMessageUnread(message)) {
      unreadMessages.add(message);
    }
  }
  messages = unreadMessages.toArray(new Message[]{});
}

return messages;
```

}

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Do you see any error?Which line?

Comment: I am getting this ERRor: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at com.D3Admin.Email.EmailUtils.getAuthorizationCode(EmailUtils.java:240)
 at com.D3Admin.Email.Utilities.GetActivationEmail(Utilities.java:73)